# how to compare the elemnts of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Given a non-empty array, return true if there is a place to split the array so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side.

Comment: My guess is homework! So have you tried doing anything yourself, or are you simply wanting somebody else to do it for you?

Comment: ihave tried doing aomething

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and 
[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a free coding or tutorial service. You have to **show** that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: So what have you tried doing? What code have you written? In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: $outString = "<<>>";
$myString = "Game On";
 echo substr($outString, 0,4).PHP_EOL;
 //echo str_replace($outString, $myString, );
//echo  str_replace(search, substr($outString, 0 ,4), $myString)

echo $myString.substr($outString ,0)

Comment: i am not able to put my string in betwween the outstring

Comment: And how does that code dump relate to your original question?

Comment: [How to ask about homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* implementation. Admit that the question is homework. Be aware of school policy regarding outside help. Never use code you don't understand.

Comment: Rather than add code or other information as a comment, feel free to [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) so that the information is easier to find.

Comment: $outString = "<<>>";
$myString = "Game On";
 echo substr($outString, 0,4).PHP_EOL;

echo $myString.substr($outString ,0)

Comment: So the code you've written doesn't contain any arrays, only a bit of string manipulation; so in what way does it offer any attempt at your homework?

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem up into smaller problems.

The array we will be using is:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

First thing first:

**Understand the problem**

In order to compare the left side with the right side you need to split the array until the sums of both sides are equal, or until there are no more items to sum.

Visually that would look something like this:

```
•  ••••
••  •••
•••  ••
••••  •
```

**Problem: *Can* the array be split into two parts?**

It is always a good idea to find out if what you are trying to do is even possible, or if doing it even makes sense.

With this problem we need at least 2 items in the array in order to split it into two parts. So, if the array has fewer than 2 items then we can safely return `false` and call it a day:

```
if (count($array) < 2) {
    return false;
}
```

**Problem: How to go through the array**

The array needs to be split after each item in the array. So, we need to go through the array item by item.

```
| • | • | • | • | • |
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

We only need to split the array at 1, 2, 3 and 4. In other words, we should start after the first item and stop before the last item:

```
$length = count($array);
for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
    echo "Split after {$i}\n";
}
```

**Problem: How to get the left/right side from the array**

Getting the left and right side is a simple matter of extracting them from the array.

```
$left  = array_slice($array, 0, $i);
$right = array_slice($array, $i);
```

If you put that into the loop and output it you will get something like this:

```
1 | 2 3 4 5
1 2 | 3 4 5
1 2 3 | 4 5
1 2 3 4 | 5
```

**Problem: Sum and compare**

PHP has a `array_sum()` function that sums values in arrays:

```
if (array_sum($left) === array_sum($right)) {
    return true;
}
```

**One solution**

```
function my_func($array) {
    if (count($array) < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    $length = count($array);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $left  = array_slice($array, 0, $i);
        $right = array_slice($array, $i);
        if (array_sum($left) === array_sum($right)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var_dump(my_func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // false
var_dump(my_func([7, 1, 2, 3, 1])); // true: 7 = (1 + 2 + 3 + 1)
```

Comment: Please vote on the content of the answer and not the question. (**Very nice answer!**, even though I wouldn't answer such a low quality question)

Comment: Yeah I know, but I felt like writing something. Someone may stumble upon this and find it to be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

(Assuming our input array contains numbers.)

Start by adding all the elements of the array to each other (total sum).  Then iterate through the array and add each element to each other as we go (cumulative sum).  If during our iteration we discover that our cumulative sum is equal to half the total sum, we know that the other members of the array will also add up to the half sum, and hence the array can be split.

```
<?php
function can_split(array $numbers) {
    $total_sum      = array_sum($numbers);
    $half_sum       = $total_sum / 2;
    $cumulative_sum = 0;
    foreach($numbers as $num)   {
        $cumulative_sum    += $num;
        if($cumulative_sum == $half_sum)
            return true;
    }
}

var_dump(can_split(array(1)));             // null
var_dump(can_split(array(1,2,3)));         // true
var_dump(can_split(array(10,1,9)));        // true
var_dump(can_split(array(3,5,9)));         // null
var_dump(can_split(array(1.5,2,3,3,3.5))); // true
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!